# Rails2 add middlware from gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I have gem with generators(one for rails3 one for rails2). And i need to add middleware layer. Rails 3 generators add it great. How can i do it in rails2 generator?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**Rails since 2.3** is a Rack based and allows you to add custom middleware in a stack.

you need to know the middleware class_name before, then add it to config/environment.rb, like this:

```
 config.middleware.use "CustomClass"
```

then check the stack:

```
 rake middleware
```

Comment: And how to add it from generator??

Comment: missed you point. you can append it to config/environments/* specific environment